# Else without if error: I dont understand why java isn't recognizing my if statment

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

At line 53 it is giving me an error of else without if. I clearly have an if statement, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong to make java not recognize it. I've tried moving around the braces and nothing is working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Quiz6
{

    public static void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println(
                            "\n\tAuthor: Allen Watson \n" +
                            "\tClass: \tCSCI 1250-001 \n" +
                            "\tDate: \t10/09/2013 \n" +
                            "\tLab: \tQuiz6 \n");
    }

    public static double calculatePay(int hourWorked, double hourlyRate)
    {
        double dPay;
        dPay = (hourWorked * hourlyRate);
        return dPay;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat dfMoney = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
        String strName;
        int iCount;
        int iDaysWorked;
        int iTotalHoursWorked;
        int iSingleDayHours;
        double dHourlyRate;
        final byte WEEK = 7;

        displayInfo();

        System.out.print("\tWhat is your name: ");
        strName = Keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n\tHow many days did you work this week: ");
        iDaysWorked = Keyboard.nextByte();
        System.out.print("\n\tHow much do you make an hour: ");
        dHourlyRate = Keyboard.nextDouble();

        if(dDaysWorked <= WEEK);
        {
            for(iCount = 1; iCount <= iDaysWorked ; iCount++)
            {
                System.out.print("\tHow many hours did you work on the day"+iCount+":");
                iSingleDayHours = Keyboard.nextInt();
                iSingleDayHours += iTotalHoursWorked;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            bDaysWorked = 0;
            System.out.print("A week can only have seven days");
        }

        calculatePay(iTotalHoursWorked,dHourlyRate);

        System.out.print("Hello "+strName+", you worked a total of "+iTotalHoursWorked+" hours over "+iDaysWorked+" days.");
        System.out.print("\nWith am hourly rate of "+dfMoney(dHourlyRate)+" you made "+dfMoney(dPay)+".");

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to count your line numbers.  Where's the error?

Comment: The semicolon is the end of the statement. The curly braces `{}else{}` have to come _before_ the end of the `if` statement - so before the semicolon

Comment: Please follow proper coding conventions and use 3+ spaces for indentation inside loops, classes, methods, etc...

Comment: In addition, `dDaysWorked` hasn't been defined. You probably meant `iDaysWorked`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
if(dDaysWorked <= WEEK); // remove the ;
```

That trailing `;` is making Java believe that the `if` statement is finished, and the `{}` block after it is outside the `if` condition, consequently the `else` part has no matching `if` preceding it.

This is a rather frequent bug, and a hard one to spot. If it weren't for the `else` block, the code would have compiled correctly, but it would have been wrong. Bottom line: never, ever put a `;` in the opening line of an `if`, `for` or `while` statement.

Comment: I'm not getting an error that java isn't returning my dPay variable from my calculatePay method i called. Line 20 and 59.

Comment: @user2792997 If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left. Regarding your new question: you forgot to declare a local variable to store the value returned by `calculatePay`. Do this: `double dPay  = calculatePay(iTotalHoursWorked,dHourlyRate);`

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking questions, but i"m relatively new to java. I have fixed all of the thing that we've talked about, but now it is telling my that my iTotalHoursWorked varible is has not been initialized. Lines 58 and 49.

Comment: @user2792997 always initialize your variables when you first declare them ... `iTotalHoursWorked = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

```
if(dDaysWorked <= WEEK); - remove last ;
```